# Swift 3 Can't get function called with UIWindow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwindow

```
    let PostButton: UIButton = {
    let pB = UIButton(type: .system)
    pB.setTitle("Post", for: .normal)
    pB.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size:18)
    pB.setTitleColor(UIColor .green, for: .normal)
    pB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(postingTextPost), for: .touchUpInside)
    return pB
}()


func postingTextPost(){

...

}

func setupTextWindow(){

    let window: UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = window.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    window.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    window.addSubview(PostBarContainer)
    window.addSubview(PostBar)
    window.addSubview(PostButton)

    PostBarContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    PostBarContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    PostBarContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    PostBarContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    PostBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: PostBarContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    PostBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: PostBarContainer.widthAnchor, constant: -80).isActive = true
    PostBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: PostBarContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    PostButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: PostBarContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    PostButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true
    PostButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: PostBar.rightAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
    PostButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: PostBarContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true

     }
```

I have some code within a `UIViewController` to execute a post function. However, within `UIWindow`, I cannot get the function to be called "its probably the smallest problem ever". The function is also inside the `viewcontroller` too. Its nothing to do with the function, its just not being called through the #selector on PostButton.

I know there is something I am missing here, but in terms of executing functions inside a keywindow, what is best practice? I know that everything shouldn't be thrown into the viewcontroller anyways, but yeah, would be great for some advice/tips too! <3

Comment: Please try adding target as this: pB.addTarget(self, action: "postingTextPost",  for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: @user1000 Yeah Xcode corrected it to: pB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(postController.postingTextPost), for: .touchUpInside). Still no luck

Comment: In which class are you writing this code?

Comment: @user1000 postController

Comment: What is your purpose of doing this? Why are you using window like this?Have you tried to use a view instead?I think you should not use UIWindow like this

Comment: @user1000 Just so it overlays everything inside the view. As this is rooted through a set of other controllers I need to use Keywindow so it will go over everything inside.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of what you want?

Comment: @user1000 I already have it all fine visually, its just getting this function to work button to work outside of the function with UIWindow. i can pull the button into the function and make it work, however this then limits of how I can use it with other things in the controller. As I then would need to pull more objects through. Such as PostBar etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is the button's action not being recognized, or is it just not calling the correct function?

If the guesture isn't being recognized then i believe this has something to do with the parent view being the UIViewController, and not the UIWindow. You are initializing the button and adding the guesture recognizor setting the parent as "self". Self in this case would be the UIViewController, when it reality the parent view needs to be the UIWindow. I would recommend changing window to be a class level constant, then change your guesture recognized line to

```
pB.addTarget(window, action: #selector(postingTextPost), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer, however about what you said. The gesture is being recognised, the button is working but the selector is not being called. I tried this an got and error so I think we are getting somewhere now!! Its throwing an exception of              Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWindow postingTextPost]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f86a9709480'

Comment: @zak Oh my gosh, I'm surprised I missed this, the selected needs to point to a function, so I'm thinking the error is you forgot the parenthesis on the function. replace the selector with #selector(postingTextPost())

Comment: Yeah still no luck mate, it is finding the function but just not calling it when running it. Still haven't fixed this, really annoying.